# Cannot start the executor - Trycatch error in uipath

Tags: exception, try-catch, uipath, uipath-activity

In a UiPath windows process, I am trying to throw an error inside a try catch block. Inside the try, two assign activities are added and bot is able to pass through those activities successfully, and then I have assigned a throw activity for testing. The bot throws the error but fails to move to the exception part, and it fails with the error "Cannot start the executor".

**Error message: **

```
system.Exception: test   at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at UiPath.Executor.BaseRunner.EndExecute(IAsyncResult result)
   at UiPath.Executor.InProcessRunner.EndExecute(IAsyncResult result)
   at UiPath.Core.Activities.ExecutorInvokeActivity.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

I have tried adding only throw activity in the try block and to print the exception message in the catch block. But it throws an error in the try block, but it failed to print the exception message in the catch block with the cannot start the executor error.

Also, I have tried updating all the packages. But still the error remains the same.

Comment: Please show us the workflow. This will help to identify what might be wrong with it and find a solution.

Comment: Sounds so me that you did not add the ```SystemException``` to the Catch block. Can that be?